# Setting Html.TextBoxFor value with jQuery is not reflected in Model POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an account page where a user can update his/her profile picture. I use Amazon S3 to store the images so after a successful upload, I return the image URL to populate the image `src` and a `TextBoxFor` with a value of the URL. However, when I submit my form, the model that is submitted to my POST still contains the desktop filename instead of the Amazon S3 URL.

Here's my ajax call that (upon success) populates an `img` field and a `TextBoxFor` field:

```
$.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Account/UploadProfImageToS3Return",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#profile-image").attr("src", data);
                $("#profImage").attr("value", data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //TODO: Indicate Error
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
        });
```

Here is my `Html.BeginForm`:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("General", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
       <img id="profile-image" src="@Model.Artist.ImageURL" alt="Profile Image" />

       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Artist.ImageURL, new { @name = "profImage", @id = "profImage", @type = "file" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-form" />
        </div>
}
```

The file, when added to the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Artist.ImageURL, new { @name = "profImage", @id = "profImage", @type = "file" })`

is called: `20507471_10214.jpg` and after the file is uploaded the value of that `TextboxFor` is now `https://s3.amazonaws.com/unlink/profile-picture/xxxxxxx.jpg` (because I update the field after AJAX success)

But when I set a breakpoint on my POST here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult General(Artist artist)
```

and I inspect the `artist.ImageURL` it still equals `20507471_10214.jpg`

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT, image to prove that the value/src attribute of each is being set properly:

[image]

Comment: What does the rendered HTML of the view look like?

Comment: @prd added an image for you, both src and value are being updated in html correctly

Comment: @prd pretty sure this has to do with ModelState on submit but I don't know how to Clear() the model state before posting so that I get the updated model in my post ActionResult. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not related, but remove the pointless `@name = "profImage"` - fortunately that does nothing at all (and if it did work, then model binding would fail)

Comment: I now see from your self answer that you assumed that would work. The model in the POST method needs to be the same as the model in the view (or you use the `[Bind(Prefix="Artist")]` attribute). In any case you should never use data models in view when editing data - always use a view model

Comment: From the screenshot, your `name` attribute is not overridden. It's still set to "Artist.ImageURL". You need to use `Name="profImage"` (with uppercase N) to override the attribute. But, it's better to do what Stephen suggested above.

Comment: @adiga, Please, never ever ever do that

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes yes, I know. I was just pointing out why `name` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Well alright then, so a workaround is to not use:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Artist.ImageURL, new { @name = "profImage", @id = "profImage", @type = "file" })`

and to instead use something like this, with a hidden form element to bind the value on submit...odd, but works:

```
<input name="profImage" id="profImage" type="file" />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Artist.ImageURL)
```

I assign the S3 URL value to the hidden form upon AJAX success with:

```
$("#Artist_ImageURL").attr("value", data);
```

Comment: That cannot possibly work since `name="profImage"` has no relationship to the model property which is `ImageURL` or an object named `Artist`. I can only assume you have done something stupid like the model in the POST method is not the same as the model in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke the point here is that I'm just using a normal HTML input element to capture the file instead of a TextBoxFor. However, you're right, I forgot to state that upon AJAX return I populate the HiddenFor field with the return URL value

Comment: What you are not understanding is that you are not binding correctly. You should have a view model with a `HttpPostedFileBase` property to bind to the fine input, and a separate `string` property to bind the name of the file to (although it does not really make sense to have that property since its already included in the `HttpPostedFileBase`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke as someone who has not used `HttpPostedFileBase` could you post an answer with the correct way to do this? I'm not posting a file, I'm posting a url string though, if that changes anything...

Comment: But your input is `type = "file`, and you using `FormData` with the relevant ajax options to post the file, so now it even more unclear what you are doing (and as a side note, delete the first `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in the ajax call - fortunately the 2nd `contentType: false,` overrides it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need the `type="file" because I need a file picker. When an item is selected from file picker, I have jQuery that tracks a "change" on that input element. jQuery takes that filestream and sends it via AJAX to my controller that parses the filestream and uploads it to S3 and returns the S3 URL. Everything works just fine. The ajax DOES post a file, the form itself does NOT, it posts a string url that is returned by that AJAX call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174700/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jordan-lewallen).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add new image-url from received from Amazon S3 to formData like this

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Account/UploadProfImageToS3Return",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#profile-image").attr("src", data);
            $("#profImage").attr("value", data);

            //imageUrl corresponds to the Artist model property.
            formData.append("imageUrl",data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //TODO: Indicate Error
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, be very carefully if you are using Chrome, Chrome do not update the css and JS files inmediatly, I recomend to you, use firefox to develop.

Maybe, when you edit the ´name´ tag, you maybe edit some behavior and this is not how MVC wait the response, can you try to delete the ¨@name = "profImage"¨ part and then check the behavior

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the question